# Using column_names.include? to protect against SQL Injection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails API that handles requests from my front end. These requests include query parameters in the url for refining and sorting results from the database. An example URL query looks like this:

`http://localhost:8000/clients?_sort=name&_order=DESC&_start=0&_end=10`

My index method in my controller grabs these params and uses them for filtering and sorting:

```
def index
  @all_clients = Client.all
  response.headers['X-Total-Count'] = @all_clients.count

  if (Client.column_names.include?(params[:_sort]))
    if (params[:_order] == 'ASC') 
      @clients = Client.filtered(params[:_start].to_i, params[:_end].to_i).order("#{params[:_sort]} asc")
    else
      @clients = Client.filtered(params[:_start].to_i, params[:_end].to_i).order("#{params[:_sort]} desc")
    end
  end

  json_response(@clients || @all_clients)
end
```

the `filtered` method is a scope which looks like this:
`scope :filtered, -> (_start, _end) { limit(_end-_start).offset(_start) }`

My question is this: by using `Client.column_names.include?` to check if `params[:_sort]` is a valid attribute to sort by, am I effectively whitelisting against SQL Injection? If not, how could I alter this code to protect against SQL Injection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important thing to consider here is not "the whitelisting of params" (since you're already cherry-picking which parameters to use anyway, rather than blindly using the whole `params` hash for something), but rather **how you are constructing the SQL**.

There are two potential injection areas in the code:

```
limit(_end-_start)
```

Is this vulnerable? **No.** If `_end` or `_start` are anything besides integers, then the code will just fail with an error message - such as:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `-' for "DROP_TABLE":String
>
> or
>
> ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): 3.14159

```
order("#{params[:_sort]} desc")
```

Is this vulnerable? **Yes.** (But not easily.) [This page](https://rails-sqli.org/#order) gives a concrete example:

```
params[:_sort] = "(CASE SUBSTR(password, 1, 1) WHEN 's' THEN 0 else 1 END)"
```

You should *never use direct string interpolation in SQL*, unless you are absolutely 100% sure that the string is "safe". In this case, you could just write it as:

```
order(params[:_sort] => :asc)
```

Comment: Also worth noting is that there may be some columns you don't *want* the user to be able to order by. (E.g. recovery question, or phone number, or bank balance, or ... ?) -- In which case yes, you should also implement an explicit whitelist.

Comment: This is excellent, thanks for the answer Tom. Your suggested code change is exactly the place I was concerned about and I couldn't get the syntax right without using string interpolation.

Comment: You can also use bound parameters - `.order("? ASC", params[:_sort])`.